# When downloading HLS video with FFMPEG it does not download the audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a problem, when I try to download an HLS video with FFMPEG, it downloads the video track, but it doesn't find the AUDIO. When running the HLS .m3u8 file in a player, it plays normally, audio and video, but when trying to download, it shows an error message saying that the audio cannot be found.

**I'm running the following command:**

ffmpeg.exe -i "https://teste-etv.espiritismo.tv/437602.m3u8" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 96k teste-hls.mp3

**Displays the following error when trying to download the audio:**

```
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Skip ('#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS')
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-1080p.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[https @ 0000021b5e10ee00] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-720p.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[https @ 0000021b5e10ee00] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-540p.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[https @ 0000021b5e10ee00] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-360p.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-1080p_00001.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-1080p_00002.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-720p_00001.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-720p_00002.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-540p_00001.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-540p_00002.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-360p_00001.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Opening 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602-360p_00002.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels, fltp): unspecified sample rate
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels, fltp): unspecified sample rate
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Could not find codec parameters for stream 5 (Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels, fltp): unspecified sample rate
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[hls @ 0000021b5d9ad940] Could not find codec parameters for stream 7 (Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels, fltp): unspecified sample rate
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, hls, from 'https://appsetv.b-cdn.net/hls/437602/437602.m3u8':
  Duration: 00:01:41.00, start: 2.083333, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 2509173
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 2509173
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 2509173
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1205957
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1205957
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1205957
  Program 2
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1165600
    Stream #0:4: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1165600
    Stream #0:5: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1165600
  Program 3
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 656245
    Stream #0:6: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 656245
    Stream #0:7: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 656245
Output #0, mp3, to 'teste-hls.mp3':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved in two ways:

Adding `-map` to map the audio track or adding the parameter `-analyzeduration 5G` (This command increases the time to check ffmpeg in the file.)

Examples:

**-map 0:1**

```
ffmpeg -i https://teste-etv.espiritismo.tv/437602-1080p.m3u8 -map 0:1 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 96k teste-hls.mp3
```

OR

**-analyzeduration 5G**

```
ffmpeg.exe -analyzeduration 5G -i https://teste-etv.espiritismo.tv/437602.m3u8 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 96k teste-hls-3.mp3
```

** The solution was found through contributions to the ffmpeg user forum on the mailing list.